# Binding spinbox to textbox

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox, tkinter-entry, spinbox

How can we get the value of a Spinbox (from 1 to 10) then multiply it into a number (ex: 100)? And then display the result into a textbox in TKINTER???

I tried the `.get()` method to get the value, then I multiplied it by 100. Then I used the `.insert()` method to display the result in a textbox, but it didn't work that well

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre] in order to identify the issue.

Comment: Just saying "it didn't work" isn't helpful. Please show the smallest but complete example possible which illustrates what you tried, and what the error message is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> How can we get the value of a Spinbox (from 1 to 10) then multiply it
> into a number (ex: 100)
>
> > I tried the .get() method to get the value, then I multiplied it by
> > 100. Then I used the .insert() method to display the result in a textbox, but it didn't work that well

- Add three widgets; `Spinbox`, `Text` and `Button`
- Create function called `value_changed`

Edit: re-work in `value_changed()`

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


# root window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
root.resizable(False, False)
root.title('Spinbox Demo')

def value_changed():
    cal = current_value.get()
    y = 100
    ca= int(cal) * y
    textbox.insert(tk.END, ca)

        
textbox = tk.Text(root, width=25, height=5)
btn = tk.Button(root, text=r'Click', command= value_changed)
 
# Spinbox
current_value = tk.StringVar(value=1)
spin_box = ttk.Spinbox(
    root,
    from_=1,
    to=10,
    textvariable=current_value,
    wrap=True)
 
spin_box.pack()
textbox.pack()

btn.pack(pady =10)

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Are you aware that this isn't doing what the user wants? They want to multiply a number times the value in the spinbox. For example, setting the number to 4 should yield 400, not 100 4s.

Comment: OP  didn't say anything.

Comment: It's clear to me that they want to multiply two numbers.